# how to add a space before a line in python

Tags: python-3.x, printing

I want to print 2 space before every line of my code's output. 
My code:

```
n = int(input())
for row in range(1, n+1):
    for column in range(1, n+1):
        print(column, end='   ')
    print('')
```

input:

```
5
```

My output:

```
1   2   3   4   5
1   2   3   4   5
1   2   3   4   5
1   2   3   4   5
1   2   3   4   5
```

The output I want:

```
  1   2   3   4   5
  1   2   3   4   5
  1   2   3   4   5
  1   2   3   4   5
  1   2   3   4   5
```

Comment: You want 2 spaces before every number, see [Live-Demo](https://repl.it/repls/CautiousMagentaAbilities#main.py)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
n = int(input())
for row in range(1, n+1):
    for column in range(1, n+1):
        print('  ',column, end=' ') # we print some whitespace in front of every character and at the end.
    print('')
```

This code prints 2 spaces before and 1 space after, like the output that you want.

Comment: @Shakiib I corrected it. It should work as expected now.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by putting the whitespace in before the column value:

```
n = int(input())
for row in range(1, n+1):
    for column in range(1, n+1):
        print('    ', column, end='')
    print()
```

This also removes the extra whitespace that your existing solution puts on the end of each line (though if you wanted that back, simple add more space to the 2nd `print` - i.e. `print('    ')`)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [join](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_join.asp) method for strings:

```
n = int(input())
for row in range(1, n+1):
    print( "  " + "  ".join([str(x) for x in range(1, n+1)]) )
```